# Android Picasso is not loading image from Azure Emulator Storage

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, azure-blob-storage, picasso, azure-emulator

I have a Image saved inside of Azure Storage Emulator uploaded using WebApi in this local Url
`http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/imagesprofile/bvv.jpg`

I can access by browser, it instantly download it, but when I tried to use with Android Picasso, it didn't work! So I first created a Container with the public permission :

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
                   CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("imagesprofile");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        container.SetPermissions(
        new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
```

And to Upload the image:

```
public async Task uploadImage(string ctn,string profileName,byte[] imageSource)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
                    CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ctn);

        CloudBlockBlob block = container.GetBlockBlobReference(profileName + ".jpg");
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imageSource, writable: false))
        {
           await block.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
        }
    }
```

But when if I try to read this URL with Picasso, I got nothing :

```
Picasso.with(this).load("http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/imagesprofile/bvv.jpg")
            .transform(new CircleTransform()).into(photo);
```

Comment: You can enable Picasso Logging which is very useful in these cases `Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);`. Please post the output from the logcat.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the IP address of current device. So if you run it on phone, it will point to phone. So the question is where do you expect the image to be loaded from?

Comment: @VladMatvienko good point, I fingered it out. I use NodeJS iisexpress to test my WebApi with local devices, so i did change the Ip address port to 3000, that I'm using with node! So now its working!